# MySQL query inside a function

Tags: php, function, mysqli

I have that code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM User");
echo("users: " . $result->num_rows ."<br/>");

function echoUserNum()
{
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM User");
    echo("users: " . $result->num_rows ."<br/>");
}
echoUserNum();
```

It prints the number of users only once (first echo call). Where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$mysqli` is out of scope in the function `echoUserNum`. Try global, or pass the connection

```
function echoUserNum()
{
    global $mysqli;
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM User");
    echo("users: " . $result->num_rows ."<br/>");
}
```

or

```
function echoUserNum($mysqli)
{
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM User");
    echo("users: " . $result->num_rows ."<br/>");
}
echoUserNum($mysqli);
```

Comment: Thank you :) I have no experience with PHP, I was looking at it from JavaScript perspective :)